# Drive Share between 2 Domain(s) Controllers to Client Desktop

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain, drive

Have 2 Servers both running Server essentials 2012R2 and a Client running 10 Pro

Let's call it Domain MAIN and Domain AUX the client logs on to Main and has normal access to the MAIN's resources. There is a Folder on the AUX that Client needs to access.

MAIN domain has internet access for users & AUX has no internet for users

I put in a hub and manually assigned IP address for each server on their **2nd Nics** and from MAIN server I can assess AUX just fine I even mapped a drive from AUX that is accessible on MAIN by shortcut on it's desktop and in my computer. So MAIN can access AUX just fine thru my 2nd connection

So far so good

PROBLEM: The Client can't access the Mapped drive that exists on MAIN and a shortcut to the drive that I made won't work either and the error is *problem with shortcut* Yet that shortcut works perfectly from the server

I'm stumped

Answer (score 0):

The mapped drive exist only in your current user login, aka in HCU. You can't share that for that reason.

A more convenient approach will be to make a DFS namespace on both side for that folder. A local copy will be hold on each server (one already, but the dfs will make it span on the other server). (Both domain must be in the same forest)

Another approach would be to add routing between those two network, without the need of the second NIC (VLAN, router config, etc..) That way you could control who access what with some ACL. With routing between those LAN, you could easily add some GPP or script to add that shared folder.

Comment: Thank you for what appears to be a great solution HOWEVER Essentials is missing this functionality as far as I can see. The DFS namespace looked like the perfect solution, except I can not find it in this OS version.

Any other possibility ?

Comment: @22comp The routing idea wouldl work, you can put a router to link both network ?

Comment: I could use a router BUT I want no possible communications between the 2 networks from different departments.

Comment: I can't believe that Microsoft could OMIT DFS Namespace from the Server 2012R2 Essentials Grrr  and get this in Services DFS is a running service. There must be a way to access this functionality  or possibly in-place upgrade to Full server ?  Anyway I ended up installing Allway Sync x64 freeware from cnet  seems to get it done